# Can't open Bootstrap dropdown using Javascript

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap dropdown menu that works fine interactively.  Now I'd like to open it programmatically using Javascript, as part of a tutorial, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's the HTML that defines the dropdown:

```
<div class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle tkr-username" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Account
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home">Profile</a>
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/login">Log out</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Following the Bootstrap docs, I'm trying to open the dropdown with this code:

```
$('#navbarDropdown').dropdown('show');
```

It appears to have no effect... but actually when I step through the code in the debugger, I can see that the dropdown is being shown, but then immediately is hidden again after my function that called the above code finishes.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Use `$('#navbarDropdown').dropdown('toggle');` and see if that works. Also , have a look [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#methods) there is no `show` method .

Comment: @Swati ```dropdown('toggle')``` also has no effect.  (And [there is a show method](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/dropdowns/#methods) in newer versions of Bootstrap; the link you posted is for an older version.)

Comment: Sorry i was not knowing that.Between that also work fine check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb14d5uf/)

Comment: i believe you can just do document.getElementById('navbarDropdown').click();